# How do you run a function when an iAd is clicked?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iad, banner-ads

I have read up on the iAd docs and am familiar with the delegate methods and there doesn't appear to be a method that runs when an iAd Banner ad is clicked.

I want to be able to pause the game when the ad is clicked:

```
[self pause];
```

Is there an App Delegate method that runs or some other method that I can run so I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use these `delegate` methods of `iAD` :

Called when the `user tapped banner view`.

```
- (BOOL)bannerViewActionShouldBegin:(ADBannerView *)banner willLeaveApplication:(BOOL)willLeave
{
   [self pause]
   return YES;
}
```

Called after a `banner view` `finishes` executing `an action` that covered your `application’s user interface`.

```
- (void)bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner
{ 
   [self play]
}
```